# karma Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: node.js, jasmine, webpack, karma-runner, vuejs2

I use karma + jasmine to write test cases for vue and webpack, and it once worked. But after I upgrade vue for 1 to 2, and update vue-loader accordingly, it starts to give error.

Now when I run karma start karma.config.js, it give me error like:

> Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
>     Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
>     at test/index.js:8995

My **karma.config.js** is:

```
var webpackConf = require('./webpack.config.js')
delete webpackConf.entry

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'tests/unit-test.html',
      // Optional 
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
       subPageTitle: 'A sample project description',
       groupSuites: true,
       useCompactStyle: true,
       useLegacyStyle: true
    },
    // this is the entry file for all our tests.
    files: [
      {pattern: './test/index.js', watched: false},
    ],
    // we will pass the entry file to webpack for bundling.
    preprocessors: {
      './test/index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    // use the webpack config
    webpack: webpackConf,
    // avoid walls of useless text
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    singleRun: true,
    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-webpack',
      'karma-htmlfile-reporter'
    ]
  })
}
```

My **webpack.config.js** is:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client','./index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../output/static'),
        publicPath: '/',
        //filename: '[name].[hash].js'
        filename: 'main.js'
        //chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/, 
                loader: 'vue'   
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel?presets=es2015',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    },
       plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            inject: true
        })
    ]
}
```

Looks like the `es6` export syntax is not translated correctly. Also, I did not know where to take a look at the **test/index.js:8995** because this is auto generated by `webpack`. The real **index.js** is quite simple, just 2 lines:

```
var testsContext = require.context('.', true, /\.spec\.js$/)
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)
```

How to debug this and what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you open chrome and inspects line 8995 of the index file to see what is the line that causing error?

Comment: I would like to try, however, this is a automatic generated script, which a lot of clause do not make much sense to me. After I took a look at it, I just felt there is something wrong with webpack config.